# Updating checkboxGroupInput based off selection from previous checkboxGroupInput

Tags: r, checkbox, input, shiny

I have multiple inputs for a ggplot function that creates a heatmap of a strikezone.

What I am trying to do is to have the "HitType" and "PlayResult" checkbox inputs appear if ONLY the "In Play" box is selected within the "PitchResult" checkbox.

With my current code, the "HitType" and "PlayResult" checkboxes are overruling the other checkboxes above and affecting the ggplot's data shown to only be data that is "In Play".

I want to be able to select all data, whether the data is "In Play" or not in play ("StrikeCalled","BallCalled",etc.).

I've read about the shinyjs package but I'm not sure if that's what I need here.

```
data$Date <- as.Date(data$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")
PitchTypeList <- c("Fastball","Cutter","Sinker","Curveball","Slider","Changeup" = "ChangeUp","Splitter")
PitchResultList <- c("Hit By Pitch" = "HitByPitch","Ball Called" = "BallCalled","Strike Called" = "StrikeCalled",
                     "Strike Swinging" = "StrikeSwinging","Foul Ball" = "FoulBall","In Play" = "InPlay")
HitTypeList <- c("Bunt","Groundball" = "GroundBall","Line Drive" = "LineDrive","Fly Ball" = "FlyBall","Popup")
PlayResultList <- c("Out","Single","Double","Triple","Home Run" = "HomeRun")

ui = fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Heatmaps - 2019 Big Ten Conference Database"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId="TeamInput", label="Select Team", choices = sort(unique(data$BatterTeam)), selected = "IOW_HAW"),
      selectInput(inputId="BatterInput", label="Select Player", choices = ""),
      dateRangeInput(input="DateRange", label="Select the date range", start=min(data$Date), end=max(data$Date)),
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "PitcherHandedness", label = "Pitcher Handedness", inline = TRUE,
                         choices = c("LHP"="Left","RHP"="Right"), selected = c("LHP"="Left","RHP"="Right")),
      fluidRow(  
      column(5, wellPanel(
       checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "PitchType", label= "Pitch Type", choices = PitchTypeList, selected = PitchTypeList) ) ),
      column(5, wellPanel(
       checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "PitchResult", label = "Pitch Result", choices = PitchResultList, selected = PitchResultList) ) )
               ),
      fluidRow(  
      column(5, wellPanel(
       checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "HitType", label= "Hit Type", choices = HitTypeList, selected = HitTypeList) ) ),
      column(5, wellPanel(
       checkboxGroupInput(inputId = "PlayResult", label = "Play Result", choices = PlayResultList, selected = PlayResultList) ) )
               )  
      ), #sidebarPanel closing

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("myZone")
             )))

server = function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(
    input$TeamInput,
    updateSelectInput(session, "BatterInput", "Select Player",
                      choices = sort(unique(data$Batter[data$BatterTeam==input$TeamInput])))
  )

  output$myZone <- renderPlot({

    data$PlateLocSide <- (data$PlateLocSide * -1)

    dataFilter <- reactive({
      data %>% filter(
        between(Date, input$DateRange[1], input$DateRange[2]),
        BatterTeam %in% c(input$TeamInput),
        Batter %in% c(input$BatterInput),
        PitcherThrows %in% c(input$PitcherHandedness),
        TaggedPitchType %in% c(input$PitchType),
        PitchCall %in% c(input$PitchResult),
        HitType %in% c(input$HitType),
        PlayResult %in% c(input$PlayResult))
    })

    ggplot(data = dataFilter(), aes(x = PlateLocSide, y = PlateLocHeight)) + 
      stat_density_2d(geom = "tile", aes(fill = ..density..), contour = FALSE, na.rm = TRUE) +
      xlim(-2.5,2.5) + ylim(0,5) + geom_point(na.rm = TRUE) +
      labs(x = "", y = "") + facet_wrap(~ Batter, ncol = 2) +
      theme(strip.text = element_text(size=20, face="bold")) +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c("white", "blue", "yellow", "red"), 
      values = scales::rescale(c(0, .05, 0.10, 0.15, .20))) + theme(legend.position="none")
  },
  width=425, height=500)


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can hide some inputs with `conditionalPanel`. But is it enough to hide the checkboxes ? (I don't get your question)

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data to make your code easier to compute ?

Comment: @gdevaux All my inputs work fine up until the last three (PitchResult, HitType, and PlayResult). Determining whether a pitch (which is one piece of data) is put in play or not will be decided in PitchResult. Not every PitchResult outcome will be defined in HitType and PlayResult. That is why I need to hide the HitType and PlayResult checkboxes if the PitchResult is not an "InPlay" checkmark.

Comment: I meant can you provide an extract of the variable "data"